# filter collection with all same records, except one column different?

Tags: java

I got the collection in java, there are identical records in this collection, only one field different, so i want to loops thru the collection pseudo like this:

```
class Pojo {
    private String name;
    private Long id;
    private String address;
    private String bank;
}
```

The collection contains this Pojo with repeated name, id, address, but bank is different
so if name, id, address same and bank different, i want the final list has just name, id, address and concatinate the bank all together with semi-colon delimited

Original collection:

```
 - Id      Name     Address                Bank
 - 1       John     123 Main Ave           BankOfAmerica
 - 2      John     123 Main Ave           Chase
 - 3      John     123 Main Ave           ING Direct
 - 4      Willy    456 My Street          Chase
 - 5      Willy    456 My Street          BankOfAmerica
```

Expected results:

```
    Name   Address            Bank
  - John   123 Main Ave       BankOfAmerica;Chase;ING Direct
  - Willy  456 My Street      Chase;BankOfAmerica
```

Comment: You tagged you question "java". Are you sure you shouldn't have tagged it "mysql" or something like that? Maybe then you'll actually get some help with your database problem.

Comment: I think the better question is "Why are you storing your data like that?".  Are you reading from a database in serious need of re-design?

Comment: 1-M table relationship, so 1 person can has many banks, the query return multi records with dups  except bank is different.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.  In general you have to show that you have already tried to solve the problem by posting the code you've written.  The POJO doesn't count.  SO volunteers will help, but you have to make an effort.

Answer (score 0):

Override equals/hash method in the `POJO` with name, id and address. Create a set and add elements continuously. Before adding check id the object is already there by calling `contains()` method. If it is there, get the object from new set, update the address by appending the address from the existing collection.